# Use ID In with conditional statement

Tags: php, mysql

How can we use SQL Statement ID IN with Conditions so that it only works with conditions for example

```
 select * from user where id in (4,5,6) ;
```

now i wanted to add some condition in query that works with these ids

```
select * from user where id in (4,5,6) and status = 1 ;
```

now if i do that it search the entire db instead of looking into 4 5 and  6 id 
how can i force it to search into 4 5 and 6 only. kindly guide me so i can do the job its not working i don't know whats going wrong with it.

Comment: Why do you think it is searching the whole table instead of limiting itself to id 4,5,and 6?

Comment: The query will works fine no problem

Comment: yes kt works with whole table as  try to run
select * from user where id in (4,5,6) and status != 1 and status !=2;

Comment: why it will check in whole db? it will check only in `user` table.

Comment: it check the whole table sorry but it should go for these four id only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from user where id in (4,5,6) and status='1';
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: status column will be of type Varchar, hence it was not working for varchar we need to specify values in ''.

Comment: it works now may be some mistake with the syntax  sorry u got -1 from someone thanks for the help bro :)

Answer (score 0):

$c =  "select *  from complaint where id in(4,5,6,7) and application_status !='Decided' and application_status !='Irrelevant'";